# TextBox in the RadGrid control doesn't make partial postback and fills the other controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik, radgrid

I have a `TextBox` (named as txt_lect_in) in [RadGrid](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx#qsf-demo-source) and I handled the `TextBox` changed event so it fills other textboxes (`gv_txt_name,gv_txt_mobile,gv_txt_address,gv_txt_email`) in the same grid.

---

**The problem is:**
The `TextBox` (`txt_lect_in`) doesn't fills the other textboxes, I know the reason but I don't know how to fix it.

After I remove the [RadAjaxManager](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/ajax/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx), it fills the other textboxes in the grid but it does full post back, how to keep the ajax manager and fill the controls at the same time?

---

```
 <telerik:radajaxmanager id="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="gv_about">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="gv_about" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="divMsgs"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>

            </UpdatedControls>
       </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:radajaxmanager>
```

---

```
<telerik:radajaxloadingpanel id="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
    </telerik:radajaxloadingpanel>
        <telerik:radgrid id="gv_about" runat="server" cssclass="RadGrid" allowpaging="True"
            pagesize="20" allowsorting="True" autogeneratecolumns="False" showstatusbar="True"
            allowautomaticdeletes="True" allowautomaticinserts="True" allowautomaticupdates="True"
            datasourceid="ObjectDataSource1" onitemdeleted="gv_about_ItemDeleted" oniteminserted="gv_about_ItemInserted"
            onitemupdated="gv_about_ItemUpdated" onitemcommand="gv_about_ItemCommand" onprerender="gv_about_PreRender"
            onitemcreated="gv_about_ItemCreated">
        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
            <commanditemsettings addnewrecordtext="&#1575;&#1590;&#1575;&#1601;&#1577;" showrefreshbutton="False" />
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="emp_num" HeaderText="&#1585;&#1602;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1581;&#1575;&#1590;&#1585;" DataField="emp_num">
                    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Silver" Width="25px"></HeaderStyle>
                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Gray"></ItemStyle>
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="name" HeaderText="&#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1587;&#1605;" DataField="name">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="220px"></HeaderStyle>
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="degree_name" HeaderText="&#1575;&#1604;&#1583;&#1585;&#1580;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1604;&#1605;&#1610;&#1577;" DataField="degree_name">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="college" HeaderText="&#1575;&#1604;&#1603;&#1604;&#1610;&#1577; &#1608;&#1575;&#1604;&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593;&#1577;" DataField="college">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="type" HeaderText="&#1606;&#1608;&#1593; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1581;&#1575;&#1590;&#1585;" DataField="type">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Delete" Text="&#1581;&#1584;&#1601;" UniqueName="column">
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
            </Columns>
            <EditFormSettings EditFormType="Template">
<EditColumn UniqueName="EditCommandColumn1" FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn1 column"></EditColumn>
                <FormTemplate>
                    <table id="Table2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="1" width="100%" border="0" rules="none"
                        style="border-collapse: collapse;" >
                        <tr class="EditFormHeader">
                            <td colspan="2" style="font-size: small">
                                <b>&#1575;&#1587;&#1578;&#1605;&#1575;&#1585;&#1577; &#1578;&#1593;&#1575;&#1585;&#1601;</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table id="Table3" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="250" border="0" class="module">

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &#1606;&#1608;&#1593; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1581;&#1575;&#1590;&#1585;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        <div id="div_lect_type">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbt_lect_type" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
            AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="false" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rbt_lect_type_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="&#1605;&#1593;&#1610;&#1606;" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="&#1605;&#1606;&#1578;&#1583;&#1576; &#1582;&#1575;&#1585;&#1580;&#1610;"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="&#1580;&#1583;&#1610;&#1583;"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </div>
    <div id="div_lect">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_lect_in" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txt_lect_in_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txt_lect_in_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters=""
            Enabled="True" MinimumPrefixLength="4" ServiceMethod="Get_Emp_AutoComplete" ServicePath="~/LectIn.asmx"
            TargetControlID="txt_lect_in" BehaviorID="ACE_txt_lect_in" CompletionListCssClass="autocomplete_completionListElement"
            CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem" CompletionListItemCssClass="autocomplete_listItem"
            EnableCaching="False">
        </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
    </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &#1575;&#1604;&#1575;&#1587;&#1605;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="gv_txt_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' TabIndex="1">
                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1608;&#1576;&#1575;&#1610;&#1604;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>

                                            <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="gv_txt_mobile" runat="server" SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll"
                                                Text='<%# Bind("tel_num") %>' PromptChar="_" Width="300px" Mask="(###)_########"
                                                TabIndex="2">
                                            </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &#1593;&#1606;&#1608;&#1575;&#1606; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1585;&#1575;&#1587;&#1604;&#1575;&#1578;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="gv_txt_address" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address") %>' TabIndex="3">
                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            &#1575;&#1604;&#1576;&#1585;&#1610;&#1583; &#1575;&#1604;&#1573;&#1604;&#1603;&#1578;&#1585;&#1608;&#1606;&#1610;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="gv_txt_email" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email") %>' TabIndex="4">
                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                           &#1575;&#1604;&#1583;&#1585;&#1580;&#1577; &#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1604;&#1605;&#1610;&#1577;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                           <asp:TextBox ID="gv_txt_degree" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("degree_name") %>' TabIndex="5">
                                            </asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                           &#1575;&#1604;&#1603;&#1604;&#1610;&#1577; &#1608;&#1575;&#1604;&#1580;&#1575;&#1605;&#1593;&#1577;:
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                       <%--    <asp:TextBox ID="gv_txt_college" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("college") %>' TabIndex="6">
                                            </asp:TextBox>--%>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "Insert" : "Update" %>'
                                    runat="server" CommandName='<%# (Container is GridEditFormInsertItem) ? "PerformInsert" : "Update" %>'>
                                </asp:Button>&nbsp;
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                                    CommandName="Cancel"></asp:Button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </FormTemplate>
            </EditFormSettings>
        </MasterTableView>
        <ClientSettings>
            <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick"></ClientEvents>
        </ClientSettings>
    </telerik:radgrid>
```

Comment: This should work, the edit form should be rendered inside the grid. Try replacing the AjaxSetting with a RadAjaxPanel around the grid, or with a regular asp:UpdatePanel control to see if this helps.

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console? Is there is ajax error, you should get that in console.

Comment: @ArindamNayak: no ,there's no error , i want to know how to use the triggers in my case